# logic iterate is not working

Tags: jsp, struts

I am working on struts web application. In that I have make use .tld files in my .JSP files.I made use of struts-logic.tld. The problem is that, logic iterate is working properly when I run my application at localhost(at my PC on Tomcate(Windows)), and also on our Linux Demo server. But when I deploy this application on client's Demo Linux Server, logic iterate is not working. Here is the code :

```
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>

<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>

<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html"%>

<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>



<div class="content"> 
        <% int i=1;
           String functionName = "submitFormforButton";
           String apend1 = "('";
           String apend2 = "')";
        %>
        <ul>
            <logic:iterate name="ProductsForm" id="arrayForMenuItems" property="arrayForMenuItems">
                <bean:define id="item" name="arrayForMenuItems" type="com.AmazonApiIntegration.ProductsForm"/>
                <li><a href ="javascript:<%=functionName+apend1+i+apend2%>"><span><bean:write name="item" property="titleOfMenuItem" /></span></a></li>
                <% i++;%>        
            </logic:iterate> 
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Is there any problem in my code or we have to configure Linux Demo Server in some manner.

Comment: Define not working? What is the error you are getting on the Demo server?

Comment: There is no error on jsp page , only it is not getting into logic iterate....Means not a single <li> ..</li> element is shown , when page is load.....

Comment: Check you have data in the list `ProductsForm.arrayForMenuItems` on your demo server.

Comment: Yes I checked during Action calling, arrayForMenuItems is initiated with proper data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `ProductsForm` to `productsForm`

Comment: I have define ProductsForm in my struts-config.xml, so I can not change , it is correct. My problem is that , it is working on one Linux Demo server but not on other Linux Demo Server...Should we have to configure Demo linux server for logic iterate in some manner.

Comment: Could it be that you have some old version of JSP cached on Linux Demo Server?

Comment: So please tell me how to check it, and what should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848994/tomcat-7-keeps-using-an-old-jsp-after-an-update

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this .... and let you know what happens........