# Tomcat 7 different behaviour

Tags: jsp, tomcat, caching, tomcat7

I'm having problems on some jsp pages using Tomcat 7.0.34, probably because I don't know in details its behaviour.

In particular I was testing some changes to a page, and the changes I made weren't visible on the browser, not always. The browers used are IE9 and Firefox 19.
I've tried to clear the cache different times but the browser still displayed sometimes the old, sometimes the new version of the page.

Then I've tried to put a syntax error in the page. Hitting the refresh button multiple times, sometimes the browser displayed a compilation problem (as expected) but sometimes it displayed the page without problems.

I've tried to remove the .class file in the work directory but nothing changed.

After about 30 minutes of inactivity I tried again opening and refreshing the page, this time I was always getting and error, but sometimes Tomcat sent to me a syntax error and sometimes a ClassNotFoundException.

I would like to know why Tomcat has this behaviour and how to make sure that it sends always the last compiled page to the browser.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848994/tomcat-7-keeps-using-an-old-jsp-after-an-update)

Answer (score 2):

I think that problem that the page is cached by a browser. 
Two options:

1)  Remove a browser cache
For example, if FireFox you can do it by pressing of Ctrl + Shift + Del

[image]

2)  Prevent a page from cache on the server side. Add the following to the page:

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i suspected that and i disabled the browser cache, but nothing changed..

Comment: Did you try stop /clean of the working / start as was suggested in the previous comment?

Comment: i tried to remove the .class from the "work" directory, as soon as i can i will try to remove also the .java..